# Bi/tricategorical coherence in terms of surface diagrams

Tags: ct.category-theory, differential-topology, higher-category-theory, string-diagrams

> Is there a typed-up version of the coherence theorem for bicategories in terms of surface diagrams? What about the GPS tricategorical coherence theorem in terms of 'volume diagrams'?

I'm aware of some [preliminary work](https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/show/Surface+diagrams) done by Todd Trimble and posted to his nlab, but the pictures are missing and the project is attempting something more ambitious than just $2$- or $3$- dimensional coherence -- I thought an explicit writeup might have cropped up in the past two decades. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I think there may be a confusion of dimension in this question. The appropriate diagrams for bicategories are string diagrams, and the appropriate diagrams for tricategories are surface diagrams.